# Compare against array of regexes in powershell

Tags: arrays, regex, powershell

I'm working on building a whitelist comparison. It works perfectly, but I'd like to add the ability to have strings containing wildcards or regex included *in the array representing the whitelist*.

Comparing the other way around - with wildcards in the installed_software variable is easy enough, but I'm not sure how to tackle comparing an array of strings that may or may not be regular expressions. Do I need to iterate against each element in the whitelist and do a regex comparison? That sounds time intense.

```
$xxxxx | foreach-object {
    $installed_software = $_
    # Compare the installed application against the whitelist 
    if ( -not $whitelist.Contains( $installed_software ) ) 
    {
        $whitelist_builder += "$installed_software"
    }
```

Comment: Can you show an example of how you'd populate `$whitelist`?

Comment: Adding values to the array is at least as expensive as reading them. *Especially* if you use the [increase assignment operator (`+=`) to create a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60708579/1701026). Instead, I recommend to use a [`HashSet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I need to iterate against each element in the whitelist and do a regex comparison? That sounds time intense.

You only need to iterate through the list *until you find a match* - the `.Where()` extension method is a good option for this kind of thing:

```
$whitelist = '\bExcel\b','\bWord\b'
$installedSoftware = "Microsoft Office 15.0 Word Application"

if(-not $whitelist.Where({ $installedSoftware -match $_ }, 'First')){
    # no patterns matching the software, add software to builder
}
```

The `'First'` mode argument instructs PowerShell that it can return as soon as it finds the first match, so if the `$installedSoftware` value had been `Microsoft Office Excel`, it would have only done 1 `-match` comparison

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to [Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69285111/45375) is to use [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string)'s ability to search for any of multiple patterns in multiple input strings:

```
# The array of whitelist regex patterns.
$whiteList = '\bExcel\b','\bWord\b'

# The array of strings to filter against the whitelist patterns.
$arrayOfStrings = 'Foo', 'A Word to the wise', 'Bar', 'Excel we shall'

# Use Select-String to match each input string against
# all whitelist patterns and return those that do *not* match.
$notWhiteListed =
  ($arrayOfStrings | Select-String -Pattern $whiteList -NotMatch).Line
```

`$notWhiteListed` then contains the following array: `'Foo', 'Bar'`.

Note:

- In PowerShell (Core) 7+ you could use the `-Raw` switch to get the (non-)matching strings directly, without the need for `(...).Line`.